# select employee on name and dep if not exists select top 1 employee for dept

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have requirement to fetch record from `employee` table with conditions on `name` and `department`. If no record exists for that name and depart, then it should return top 1 record from the `employee` for that `department`.

Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE NAME = 'SQL' AND DEPID = 1
 IF NOT EXISTS 
     SELECT TOP 1 * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE DEPID = 1
```

Can this be achived with in a single query and also considering the performance.

Comment: What do you mean by "*single query*"? Are `sub-queries` allowed?

Comment: Since you mention `Top` I assume that `Employee` table has `Primary Key`. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you in MS SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM employee
WHERE depid = 1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name = 'SQL' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

For PostgreSQL and MySQL, use:

```
SELECT * FROM employee
WHERE depid = 1
ORDER BY name != 'SQL'
LIMIT 1
```

For best performance, create compound (multi-column) index on `(depid, name)`.

Comment: I've never seen that. explain? EDIT: Nevermind, I'm an idiot. I didn't realize the literal 'SQL' was the example name he was filtering on.

Comment: `ORDER BY name != 'SQL'` will come first on exact match. Otherwise, it will pick first non-match.

Comment: I guess using `!=` or `<>` is a matter of preference - whichever suits you.

Comment: vassy's works better and makes 2 index seeks of 1 record each if there is an index on (depid, name). This one pulls all the DEPID=1 records, sorts by your condition, and then picks one.

Comment: You are wrong - if index `(depid, name)` is created, it will be single index seek.

Comment: @mvp - It cannot resolve the ORDER BY without evaluating EVERY ROW for the condition. It is NOT an index seek. I have verified it with SQL Server, but you're obviously thinking of some other RDBMS since your code doesn't syntax check in SQL Server. However, I will stand corrected if any DBMS does 2x index seeks of 1 record for your query.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi: Fixed syntax error. God, I did not think that MSSQL is that stupid that `ORDER BY` boolean does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE DEPID = 1 AND 
NAME = CASE 
       WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE DEPID = 1 AND NAME = 'SQL') 
       THEN 'SQL' ELSE NAME END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 * from employee where depid = 1 and not exists (select * from employee where name = 'SQL' and depid = 1)
union all
select * from employee where name = 'SQL' and depid = 1
```

Comment: This answer assumes there are more than 1 record where name = 'SQL' and depid = 1

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using SQL server.

A simple If exists else logic will work here.

```
If exists(SELECT 1 from employee WHERE ename='SQL' AND deptno=1)
SELECT * from employee WHERE name='SQL' AND deptno=1
else 
select top 1 * from empoyee where deptno=1
```

Comment: Last time I checked, SQL did not support `if` / `else`

Comment: @mvp SQL server RDBMS I'm using.